# Encode GET parameters on URL

Tags: java, http, url, get, encode

I made that code that works well, but I'm sure that exists something cleanest and easier to read

```
    public static String get(String url, HashMap<String, Object> args){
        if(!url.endsWith("/")) url+="/";
        args.keySet().forEach(k -> {
            try {
                args.replace(k, URLEncoder.encode(args.get(k).toString(), "UTF-8"));
            }catch (Exception ex){}
        });
        if(!args.isEmpty()){
            url+="?";
            for(Map.Entry<String, Object> arg : args.entrySet()){
                url+=arg.getKey()+"="+arg.getValue()+"&";
            }
            url = url.substring(0, url.length()-1);
        }
        return url;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the JAX-RS's [UriBuilder](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/core/UriBuilder.html):

```
public static String get(String url, Map<String, Object> args) {
    UriBuilder builder = UriBuilder.fromUri(url);
    args.entrySet().forEach(e -> builder.queryParam(e.getKey(), e.getValue()));
    return builder.toString();
}
```

Alternatively you may want to take a look at [URIBuilder](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpclient/apidocs/org/apache/http/client/utils/URIBuilder.html) from Apache.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, *don't attempt to reinvent the wheel*. Creating a URI with query parameters in a very common requirement so I strongly advise you to use a tested and trusted solution rather then writing your own.

Let me expand a bit the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51185032/1426227) posted by [Jan Hronik](https://stackoverflow.com/u/3561880). Depending on the stack you are using in your application, you can go for one of the following approaches:

### [`UriBuilder`](https://javaee.github.io/javaee-spec/javadocs/javax/ws/rs/core/UriBuilder.html) from JAX-RS (introduced in Java EE 6)

```java
public static String buildUri(String baseUri, Map<String, Object> queryParams) {
    UriBuilder builder = UriBuilder.fromUri(baseUri);
    queryParams.forEach((key, value) -> builder.queryParam(key, value.toString()));
    return builder.toString();
}
```

### [`UriComponentsBuilder`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/util/UriComponentsBuilder.html) from Spring

```java
public static String buildUri(String baseUri, Map<String, Object> queryParams) {
    UriComponentsBuilder builder = UriComponentsBuilder.fromUriString(baseUri);
    queryParams.forEach((key, value) -> builder.queryParam(key, value.toString()));
    return builder.toUriString();
}
```

### [`URIBuilder`](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpclient/apidocs/org/apache/http/client/utils/URIBuilder.html) from Apache HTTP Components

```java
public static String buildUri(String baseUri, Map<String, Object> queryParams) 
    throws URISyntaxException {
    URIBuilder builder = new URIBuilder(baseUri);
    queryParams.forEach((key, value) -> builder.addParameter(key, value.toString()));
    return builder.toString();
}
```